# Continuity True or False

Tags: real-analysis

True or false?

> If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $0$ and $f(1/(2n+7)) = g(1/(7-2n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(0)=g(0)$.

My gut tells me this is false, because when I set $(1/(2n+7)) = (1/(7-2n))$ and solve for $n$, I do not get an integer for $n$. I think I am misreading the problem or am overlooking something however...

Comment: **Hint:** What are $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(1/(2n+7))$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(1/(7-2n))$?

Comment: Why would you want to set $1/(2n+7) = 1/(7-2n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is irrelevant to the problem. (Note the that you're *given* that for each integer $n$ you have $f\bigl(1/(2n+7)\bigr)=g\bigl(1/(7-2n)\bigr)$. It does not matter that $1/(2n+7)\ne 1/(7-2n)$.)

But note:

Both of the sequences $\bigl(1/(2n+7)\bigr)$ and $\bigl(1/(7-2n)\bigr)$ tend to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. Thus, by the continuity of $f$ at $0$, one has $f(0)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }f\bigl(1/(2n+7)\bigr)$; and  by the continuity of $g$ at $0$, one has $g(0)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }g\bigl(1/(7-2n)\bigr)$.

From the above observation and the given condition that $f\bigl(1/(2n+7)\bigr)=g\bigl(1/(7-2n)\bigr)$ for each $n$, you should be able to see that the given assertion is true.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1{2n+7} \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac 1{7-2n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Continuity of $f$ and $g$ gives $f(0) = g(0)$

Answer (score 0):

It states that the two functions are equal to each other in the domain of the set of natural numbers. Zero is not in the set of natural numbers so the statement is false.
All of you are reading to much into the problem

Comment: Some mathematicians include zero in the set of natural numbers.